Why do birds not fluff up when they land on super grid transmission lines?
I’ve been testing a home brew Van de Graaff generator on my younger sister.  When I do that, her long hair fluffs up like that scene in the Pink Panther cartoons when he’s tumble dried. Puff!
Birds, especially the good ones (birds of prey) hate being touched or stroked as that transfers oils from your hand onto their feathers.  That can increase their feathers’ conductivity and hence reduce their propensity to fluff.  So they aspire to maintain low conductivity, a situation favourable to charge accumulation.
I’ve seen birds on UK super grid transmission lines (400 kV) and they still look pretty much bird like.  Why please?

Transmission lines are insulated

@Nabla  Are you sure?

birds fluff feathers by moving their skin, and a feather has a stiff core called quill ... humans do it with our hair, it's called goose bumps

The transmission lines are alternating current, so all the charge that gets stored during a half cycle gets removed during the other half

@jsotola: Is that a generic assertion that DC high-voltage lines exist, or a specific claim about the UK 400kV grid mentioned in the question?

@BenVoigt my bad ... I do not know if UK uses DC transmission lines

The UK has DC lines : https://www.nationalgrid.com/sites/default/files/documents/13784-High%20Voltage%20Direct%20Current%20Electricity%20%E2%80%93%20technical%20information.pdf

Hair "fluffs up" at high voltage. I'm not sure feathers would. Feathers are much stffer than hair.

@Nabla certainly the larger transmission lines are not insulated. There are ceramic insulators at each tower, but the cables themselves are bare metal. Insulation would be far too heavy, and make the lines significantly more expensive. Why bother when you can use a suitably insulating and free material - the air.

I feel like this is more of a physics question than an electrical engineering question. From the perspective of electrical engineering, there's not much difference between a bird sitting on a 400 kV transmission wire and a human touching a 400 kV Van de Graaff generator. The effect that that voltage has on those creatures is determined by physical properties like length and stiffness.

@PaulUszak That can increase their feathers’ conductivity ... that's thermal conductivity, not electrical conductivity

Sounds like replacing your little sister with a bird  and repeating the experiment is in order. At 400kV all the bird is going to be at about the same potential regardless of how unctuous they may be. The bird interactions with EHT lines seem to be primarily from excreting from a grounded support structure (down onto insulators) and from flying into the lines.

I’ve been testing a home brew Van de Graaff generator on my younger sister. Somewhere in the distant future, she will get you back!

@StainlessSteelRat ...and the result will be shocking!

Birds don't like to land on lines higher than tens of kilovolts, as the adjacent corona discharge becomes more uncomfortable than they can bear. They also don't like the noise and UV that comes from the corona, it scares them off. (Though, this answer would suggest otherwise. Maybe some birds are more sensitive than others.)
As to why bird feathers woudn't stand on end like your sister's hair, there's a couple of reasons.

HV lines that birds will land on are AC, so no 'static' field forms
Bird feathers are very stiff compared to hair, with thick shafts connecting them to the skin

So if a bird landed on your Van de Graaf generator, their feathers would not 'fluff up' so much.
Related: Professor said no current flows to ground
As for your claim that you've seen birds landing on 'super grid' lines, seems plausible. As I said, birds are known to stay away from lines above a certain voltage (~21kV, at least when I did some quick research) because of corona.
That said, there are HVDC lines too. Would birds land on these in preference to HV AC lines? A good question.  There would be just the initial charge equalization as the bird got close, compared to AC where the polarity changing. So for the bird, maybe their experience is comparable to approaching a Van de Graaf: as they fly closer they cross the near-wire voltage gradient which charges them up before they actually land on the wire.
Still, I bet a large bird (an eagle, say) would probably get a bigger initial wallop than a smaller bird.
And, DC lines have corona discharge too. Maybe less so than AC, but still some UV and noise that tends to scare away wildlife.
But not completely, apparently. This study points to some bird-related outages that happen on a +/- 400kV HVDC transmission line on China. tl; dr: it's mostly about bird poop.

I'm not convinced that high voltage AC would not cause hairs to fluff up. Yes, the average voltage is zero, but I would guess that instantaneous high voltage would cause hairs to repel regardless of the instantaneous polarity of that high voltage, unless RC constant/effects of hair prevented enough charge travelling through hair.

Feather shafts would be more conductive than hair, simply because of their larger diameter. So less charge gradient would form.

"as they fly closer they cross the near-wire voltage gradient which charges them up" – That phrasing sounds a little misleading. Crossing that voltage gradient causes their potential to approach the potential of the wire, but it doesn't cause their net charge to change, so I wouldn't describe it as "charging." In order for their net charge to change, they would need to come into contact with ions in the air.

Granted, their charge distribution does change as they approach the wire, so you might say that the near half of the bird and the far half of the bird are both charging (but with opposite charges).

They voltage is alternating constantly, with not much time for any kind of repelling of the feathers. There would be a small current from the capacitance of the bird to the ground and a little more than
But lets say at the peak of the cycle the line reaches 400kV and the line is 50m tall. The electric field at it's peak would be about 8kV/m
A van degraff generator about 1.5m from the ground charged to 200kV would be about 133kV/m so a lot more 'motivation' for the electrons to fluff things up.

That’s a good point about the relative gradient to ground level. That said, the proximity of metal towers to the HV lines forms local gradients and coronas.
